# vertical selector using syncfusion flutter datepicker

Tags: flutter

I've been having trouble understanding the `syncfusion_flutter_datepicker` plugin in flutter.

```
SfDateRangePicker(
  enableMultiView: true,
  navigationDirection: DateRangePickerNavigationDirection.vertical,
  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiRange,
  showNavigationArrow: true,
  initialSelectedDate: widget.start,
  initialSelectedDates: [widget.start,widget.end],
  
);
```

so how can I return the start and end dates using this plugin? I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Flutter date range picker, you can get the start and end date of the selected range by using the startDate and endDate property of the onSelectionChanged callback args.

In `initState()`, set the default values.

```
String _startDate, _endDate;
DateRangePickerController _controller;
DateTime _start, _end,_today;
 
@override
void initState() {
  _controller = DateRangePickerController();
  _startDate = DateFormat('dd, MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  _endDate = DateFormat('dd, MMMM yyyy')
      .format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)))
      .toString();
  _today=DateTime.now();
  _start = _today;
  _end = _today.add(Duration(days: 3));
  _controller.selectedRange = PickerDateRange(_start, _end);
  super.initState();
}
```

Using the `onSelectionChanged` callback get the startDate and endDate of the selected range.

```
void selectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
  setState(() {
    _startDate =
        DateFormat('dd, MMMM yyyy').format(args.value.startDate).toString();
    _endDate =
        DateFormat('dd, MMMM yyyy').format(args.value.endDate).toString();
  });
}
```

Assign _startDate and _endDate values to the Text properties to show the values.

```
SfDateRangePicker(
  controller: _controller,
  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
  onSelectionChanged: selectionChanged,
  allowViewNavigation: false,
);
```

If you have any doubt yet, please refer the following link which I mentioned below:

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12248/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-date-of-the-selected-range-in-the-flutter-date-range-picker